# Find position of a node with specific text among identical nodes using xpath

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

There is a set of trademark nodes `<tm>` in a single document. Each node `<tm>` contains the text node inside - trademark name. There may be identical nodes among `tm's` that means they have the same trademark name. I need to write the template that will add the trademark character ™ (`&#8482;`) only to the first occurrence of each trademark.

Example:

```
<doc>
  <a><tm>A</tm></a>
  <tm>A</tm>
  <tm>B</tm>
  <b><tm>B</tm></b>
  <a><b><c><tm>A</tm></c></b></a>
</doc>
```

Only the first occurrences of `<tm>A</tm>` and `<tm>B</tm>` should be processed.

The expected result is:

```
<doc>
  <a><tm>A&#8482;</tm></a>
  <tm>A</tm>
  <tm>B&#8482;</tm>
  <b><tm>B</tm></b>
  <a><b><c><tm>A</tm></c></b></a>
</doc>
```

The difficulty here is that there are identical nodes. Besides, I cannot write a separate template for each trademark, one template should match all.

Here is a draft of the solution:

```
<xsl:template match="tm">
  <xsl:variable name="text" select="text()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="same_tms" select="//tm[text()=$text]"/>
  <xsl:if test=" --- current tm is the first among $same_tms --- ">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(), '&#8482;')"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't know how to write a generic test condition that would check if the current `<tm>` is the first among `$same_tms`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a key, as in Muenchian grouping (http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml), only that with XSLT 2.0 you can use `is` instead of the `generate-id()` test you would need in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:key name="tm" match="tm" use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tm[. is key('tm', .)[1]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#8482;')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online as http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mC.

Comment: Obviously the `is` operator would also solve your approach as `. is $same_tms[1]`.